# error: failed to push some refs /github/visual Studio

Tags: github

I am raising my project to github, first I opened github and put New Repository and then I put "Repository Name" and then I choose "Private" , then create Repository", and after that a set of instructions appeared to me, then I opened the project in Visual studio and then within the Visual studio I opened the terminal and wrote these instructions that appered to me:

```
git init 
git commit -m "first"
git config --global user.email "Nour77@gmail.com"
git config --global user.name "nour-George"
git remote add origin https://github.com/nour-George/FFFF.git
git push -u origin master
```

But I got this error when I put the last instruction:

```
 error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/safaa-Haddad/Base.git'
```

How do I solve the problem and is there an error in applying the previous steps ?

Comment: please add files first before commiting files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add files before commiting files

git add .

git commit -m "Commit message"

git push -u origin master